# CSS Hover inside div elements with sub elements

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to change the color of hover for "Web Site" and "Home"

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar transparent navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand headtop" href="#">Web Site</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="headtop"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

And css this code

```
a.headtop:hover, a:hover  {
    color: #fc4c1d;
}
```

**But not working... how do I make it work?**

```
a:hover  {
```

is working for other links in body page
but **not working for the text inside div elements.**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you are using bootstrap to style your page

bootstrap add some rule to style the hover of `<a>` in .navbar some of them will be like this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
color: #333333;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

so you can see that `.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover`  has higher specificity than your

a:hover so it will beat your simple a:hover rule, which results in your fail of goal.

**the solution:**

1. give up bootstrap
2. override the rule in bootstrap for :hover
3. add id for your target `<a>` to give a higher specificity then style `#home:hover {}`
4. use !important  `a:hover { color: red !important}`

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
.navbar a:hover{
    color: #fc4c1d !important;
}
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/nukec/qL48R/2/